# Webview change color of default background img

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I'm new on kotlin and I'm having an issue with a webview that I can't understand, on my webview activity I have set a background (img1), but when I load the url into the webview the background color changes to (img2) and I can find the reason.

xml

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/webViewToolbar" />
```

Kotlin

```
val webview = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
val webSettings = webview.settings
webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webview.loadUrl(url)
```

img1

[image: IMG 1]

img2

[image]

Comment: What does your `url` look like in a browser?

Comment: @Yeldar.N is plain text with transparent background

Comment: How about that `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, "", "text/html", "UTF-8", "")`?